# SwiftUI edges become visible after scaling images to fill

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, frontend

I am new to swiftUI and I have been trying to place images in a Rounded rectangle but every time I use `scaledToFill()` The corners of the rectangle disappear.
This is my code :

```
Image("img_6").resizable()
                
                .scaledToFill()
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 55,
            style: .continuous))
                .shadow(radius: 9)
                .frame(height: 550).clipped()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifiers order is important. In your case just move `.clipShape` after `.frame`, as

tall:

[image: demo1]

wide:

[image: demo2]

```
    Color.clear
        .frame(height: 550)
        .overlay(Image("img")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill())
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 55,
            style: .continuous))
        .shadow(radius: 9)
```

*Note: `.clipped` not needed, because `.clipShape` already performs clipping*

Comment: Now we're back to not seeing the shadow.

Comment: @vacawama, try to make red shadow (for better visibility)

Comment: Yes, red shadow.  Good tip.

Comment: Knowing the modifier order is important solved a huge issue for me when I was setting the backgroundColor after clipShape. Thanks!